# Flutter/Dart - FutureBuilder bool not returning bool

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, future

I've got a boolean provided by `ChangeNotifierProvider` which grabs true or false from `SharedPreferences`.  It should update to "true" once a user has logged in.  I'm calling this boolean from a FutureBuilder. However, instead of getting the correct boolean, all I'm getting is the `CircularProgressIndicator()` indicating something has gone wrong. Here's the code;

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var socialProvider = Provider.of<SocialProvider>(context);
        return FutureBuilder<bool>(
          future: socialProvider.loadCurrentLogged(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData) {
              return
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Consumer<SocialProvider>(
                          builder: (context, socialProvider, _) =>
                              Container(
                                child: new RaisedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (snapshot.data != true) {
                                      //Do something here.
                                    } else { // } //switch end
                                  }
                                 ),
                              ),
                           ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                );
            } else {return
              Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator()
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

And here's the future provided by the `ChangeNotifierProvider`;

```
 Future<bool> loadCurrentLogged() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool currentlogged = prefs.getBool('currentlogged') ;
    return currentlogged;
  }
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh!

```
if(!snapshot.hasData)
```

should be;

```
if(snapshot.hasData)
```

Sigh...